# Realm : Property "Dummy" of type 'array' cannot be nullable

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm trying to open a realm connexion with these schemas.

```
[{
    name: 'Day',
    properties: {
        day: {type: 'int', optional: true},
        time: {type: 'string', optional: true},
    }
},
{
    name: 'Period',
    properties: {
        close: {type: 'Day', optional: true},
        open: {type: 'Day', optional: true}
    }
},
{
    name: 'Dummy',
    properties: {
        isDummy: {type: 'bool', optional: true},
        periods: {type: 'Period[]', optional: true},
    }
}]
```

I get this error : `Property "Dummy" of type 'array' cannot be nullable`.

I have no clue why I get this error. If someone can explain that to me, I would be grateful to him.

Answer (score 2):

You should just set the default value to empty list like this [], becaus you want to have empty array. So you should use this:

```
{
    name: 'Period',
    properties: {
        close: {type: 'Day[]', default: []}, // <-- change here
        .....
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
    name: 'Period',
    properties: {
       close: {type: 'Day', optional: true},
       open: {type: 'Day', optional: true}
    }
}
```

Comment: I already find a way to fix this 2 years ago, see comments on @Mohammad-f answer.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because period is an optional array on dummy schema and for unknown reason arrays cannot be nullable

Comment: Thanks, I figured out month ago that array of custom type **cannot** be nullable on realmjs

Comment: Do you know any workaround for having optional array ? @Darkilen

Comment: We used `msgpack-lite` to convert our array of complexe object to an ArrayBuffer and we stock it as a `data` value. When we use it, we turned it back to an array of complexe object. Maybe they did a update to allow array of custom type to be nullable, didn't check since months.

Comment: @Darkilen Thanks